# strange behavior when I update git files

Tags: git

Previously, if I update some files in git repo(either in IDE or vi or textedit, etc.), then "git status" will show this file as updated, so I can just use "git add" to add it;

But now, no matter where/how I update a file, "git status" won't show it as a candidate to "git add", also if I use "git add" on it, it won't show as modified when check "git status". The only thing I can do is: copy the updated file somewhere, then "git rm thisFile", then copy it back, then "git add" it. This way it will show up as modified.
For new file addition, there is no problem to just "git add" it.

I did some actions between "Previously" and "now", but I don't think it's relevant (and I don't remember exactly what I did). The question is, anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks a lot!!

I mentioned what I tried above

Comment: If you look at the last modified timestamp of one of the files that isn’t showing up as modified according to Git, what does it show? (`stat path/to/file`)

Comment: You could try the following command, on the off chance that the `assume-unchanged` bit has been toggled on for the file: `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged your-file-path`

Comment: The problem is, it's not just happening on one file, it's happening on every file I am updating... so it's like some global setting changed??

Comment: Difficult to debug. If the repo exists remotely, you could try deleting your local repo and clone the remote one. To debug further, edit one of the files and then run the command `git update-index --refresh`. See if this marks the file as updated. If not, try `git update-index --really-refresh`.

Comment: It turns out my linux just brought back the system's own git instead of my git, so the version is very old. I also found that this is the problem that other people also see on linux. So I need to keep an eye on the PATH and be sure it won't be changed somehow.